# Finding the closest common ancestor for otu1 and otu2 where otu is operational taxonomic unit

Tags: python, biopython

Having a bit of trouble getting the function to work properly

```
tree = {
    'ADBCE': [None, ('ADBC', 3.625), ('E', 17.625)],
    'AD': [('ADB', 5.25), ('A', 4.0), ('D', 4.0)],
    'ADB': [('ADBC', 4.75), ('AD', 5.25), ('B', 9.25)],
    'D': [('AD', 4.0), None, None],
    'E': [('ADBCE', 17.625), None, None],
    'ADBC': [('ADBCE', 3.625), ('ADB', 4.75), ('C', 14.0)],
    'A': [('AD', 4.0), None, None],
    'B': [('ADB', 9.25), None, None],
    'C': [('ADBC', 14.0), None, None]
}
```

otu = operational taxonomic unit

```
def ClosestCommonAncestors(otu1,otu2, tree)
```

e.g otu1 = "AD" and otu2 = C

output is = "ADBC" which is the closest common ancestor

Comment: having a bit of trouble understanding what you're asking

Comment: just returning the closest common ancestor between the two otus in the tree

Comment: Same comment as to your mar question: if you don't explain how to read your tree, most probably you won't get answers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your tree is formated like this `node : (parent, child_left, child_right)`, here is sub-optimal solution using a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) to get the ancestors of a given node :

```
def ancestor(a,tree):
    """ Return the ancestors of a until the root is reached """
    dist = 0
    while tree[a][0] != None:
        yield tree[a][0][0]
        a = tree[a][0][0]

def LCA(x,y,tree):
    """Return the last common ancestor of x and y in tree"""

    # First we build the set of all ancestors of one of the two entries.
    ancestor_x = frozenset(ancestor(x,tree))

    # Then we iterate trough the ancestors of the second entry until we find an ancestor of the first one.
    for j in ancestor(y,tree):
        if j in ancestor_x:
            return j

assert LCA("AD","C",tree) == "ADBC"
assert LCA("A","E",tree) == "ADBCE"
assert LCA("ADB","E",tree) == "ADBCE"
```

Since we build the set of all the ancestors of one of the two entries, I except this to scale poorly (especially if the tree is not balanced) but it should do the trick on small trees.